# Accessing keys/values from dictionaries nested in lists in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pygame

I've been learning a bit of pygame to bring our text-based MUD to the next level.

I've found [this tutorial](http://inventwithpython.com/chapters/) which has been really helpful. However, I want to expand on chapter 18's example and make all the green entities move around as well.

Obviously, you can't just copy/paste the earlier script that made the white block move on its own since these are just rectangles in a list and not a dictionary. So I'm wondering how one can access the keys/values in a dictionary nested within a list.

To put some code to my question:

A rectangle looks like this:

```
badGuy = {'rect':pygame.Rect(300, 100, 50, 50), 'dir':UPLEFT}
```

In the original code, it simply appended new rectangle objects into a list:

```
foods = []
for i in range(20):
    foods.append(pygame.Rect(stuff to make the rectangle)
```

is it possible to do something like

```
foods = []
for i in range(20:
    foods.append(badGuy)
```

then access the 'rect' and 'dir' keys from the badGuy dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Assuming you fix all the missing parens and other things, `foods` will end up as a list of 20 `dict`s. That's perfectly legal, and a `dict` doesn't care whether you got it directly from a variable, or from the middle of a `list`, or anywhere else. So, you can do things like:

```
print foods[0]['rect']

for food in foods:
    print food['dir']

food = random.choice(foods)
print food['rect']
```

… and so on.

Comment: One warning though: If you use the code shown in the question, with the dict held in the `badGuy` variable, you'll end up with a list containing 20 references to the same dictionary. This may cause trouble later if you try to modify the dictionary in place (with something like `enemies[0]['dir'] = DOWNLEFT` or a loop or something), as you'll end up with all of your enemies always being in the same place and facing the same way. To avoid this, you'd probably want to remake the `badGuy` dictionary inside the loop.

Comment: Awesome! So, more at Blckknght's comment, does this mean that I can interact with all 20 rects without doing food[x]['rect']? Am I able to just do food['rect'] ? because later on I do like `foods['dir'].left -= MOVESPEED `

Comment: @Mathieu: You seem to be mixing up `foods` (a list of dicts) and `food` (one of the dicts from that list). You can't use them interchangeably. In particular, you can't do `foods['dir']`. Meanwhile, you almost certainly don't want to share the same dict across all 20 of them—if you wanted that, why have a list of them in the first place? The way to do something to each dict in the list is with a for loop, as in my example: `for food in foods: food['dir'].left -= MOVESPEED`.

Comment: @abarnert Well my ultimate goal is to have 20 different rects that are able to act independently. Meaning move on their own accord, die, repopulate. I know how to do this with something like sqlite, but wonder if it's possible without that.

Comment: In the code above, `for food in foods:` will loop through the whole list. So at the first iteration `food` is the same as `foods[0]`. At the second `food` is the same as `foods[1]` etc.

Comment: @Mathieu: Have you read the [Lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) and [`for`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) sections of the tutorial, or some similar third-party tutorial? Looping over lists is one of those abstractions that's totally obvious once you get it, but confusing until you do.